# gvim cmd line offset issue when doing horizontal splits?

Tags: gvim, split

Not sure how to explain this but basically I'm using an external plugin/dll to enable fullscreen in gvim (which is very lame since this should be a built-in feature...).

The problem in when I open a window in a horizontal split, vim's cmd line gets offset up a little bit, I'd have to exit/enter fullscreen mode again to get it back to the bottom of the screen.

Here's a video demonstrating the problem: https://youtu.be/Ad__lRMoCc8

Here's my entire setup: https://github.com/vexe/vim

I truly appreciate any help as this has been frustrating me a lot...

**[Edit]** Just tested it without fullscreen, it's still the same issue. i.e. open a normal gvim window (not in fullscreen) and then open something in a horizontal split, the cmd line will get offseted as well... I would have to move the window around, maximize/unmaximize it etc to get the line back to the bottom of the window.

**[Edit]** Running gvim.exe without my _vimrc/_gvimrc, the issue is not there...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the culprit!

```
set laststatus=0
```

For some reason hiding that statusline and doing a horizontal split will cause the issue. Setting it to 1 (default value: show status line when there's more than one window) will not cause any offsetting of the cmd line!

**BUT I do NOT want a status line at all!** Does anybody know a way around this? This sounds ridiculous but is there anyway to not have the statusline and not suffer from this issue? how about an empty statusline? I tried `set statuesline=` but it didn't do anything, I still see "filename-------" in the statusline (`noruler` is also set)

**Edit:** I set the horizontal split chars to whitespace (after walking into this [caveat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7223309/vim-statusline-uses-carret-symbols-for-spaces-how-to-switch-to-spaces)) via `set fillchars=stl:\` notice the escaped space via `\`

But now I'm still stuck with the filename at the beginning of the status line.

**Edit:** Used space for statusline `set statusline=\`

But there's still an annoying empty line above the cmd line, not as annoying as the initial situation but still... if anyone has a better solution please let me know.