# Hide statusline when more than two windows open without suffering the extra hidden empty line artifact?

Tags: gvim, split, statusline

I want to hide the statusline, I don't ever use nor care about what is written in it. The problem is vim doesn't offer a way to achieve that in a convenient manner. If I just do `set laststatus=0` I will suffer from the artifact mentioned in [this question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/4725/gvim-cmd-line-offset-issue-when-doing-horizontal-splits). If I do `set laststatus=1` and     set `fillchars=stl:\` the status line will be invisible but well, still take a line of space, which is annoying...

Here's how it looks right now, slight darker background just to show you that it's blocking the text behind it and is still taking one line of space [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HvcAx.png]

Is there a way to hide the status line for good (both in single and multiple windows mode) without suffering from the artifacts mentioned in the previous question?

I'd appreciate any help, tired of fighting my tools to get them to do what I want.

Comment: I do not know the solution, but I know a plugin that mostly does the same thing: [Goyo](https://github.com/junegunn/goyo.vim). You could investigate the source code and see if you can find a solution there.

Comment: Goyo cuts even MORE of my screenspace, you can't set the bottom/top margins to 0, I don't get the point of that plugin why would anybody want less writing space?... but thanks for mentioning it cause it brought up similar plugins like vimroom, checking them out.

Comment: Wish there was a vim callback when a horizontal split happens, that way I can set laststatus to 1 when it does, and back to 0 when there are no more horizontal splits.

Comment: And no luck with all the plugins, I tried 4 'distraction free' plugins. I was always able to reproduce the the horizontal split artifact mentioned in the link in my question.

Comment: My point was not that you use Goyo, but that Goyo manages to remove the statusline with no artifacts (as far as I know). And yes, it cuts screenspace, but that is by design: The point of Goyo is to give a non distracting buffer with the desired width and height. Personally, I use this sometimes when I write code and/or prose, and I like it.

Comment: those distrationfree plugins make the statusline empty, they can't clear it, because it is not possible to have no statusline.

Comment: Is there any information that you do care about? The status line doesn't seem to be going away, so you might as well use it to show things you do care about if the things already shown aren't relevant.

Comment: @KarlYngveLervåg all the plugins modify `laststatus` and `fillchars` so I was able to reproduce the artifact mentioned in my other question. @ChristianBrabandt I guess the only way is to modify vim's code then... @muru there's nothing I really care about that much, except the line-number, filename and current % of where I am currently in the file, all of this information I can easily and quickly see by just pressing Ctrl-g so there's no point for them to be always there and me staring at them.

Answer (score 3):

It is not posssible, to completly hide the statusline, if there are multiple windows. You can tweak the StatusLine and StatusLineNC highlighting groups (Note, even if you clear those groups completly, Vim will fall back and use '=' and '^' to dispaly something sane.), but basically that line will always be shown, and can't be used to display the buffer content.
If you think about it, this makes sense, since for vertical splits, you couldn't tell where one buffer ends and the next one starts.

Comment: It would make sense if there's a horizontal split (okay I understand vim needs to visually separate the horizontal parts), but not in vertical splits (like in the picture above), it makes no sense to visually separate my buffer window from the cmd line...

Comment: yes, i meant horizontal. Anyway, there is no way around it as far as i know