# How to hide horizontal line between windows

Tags: vimrc, gvim

I set `statusline=` and `fillchars=vert:\|` and the result is for horizontal is here when I try `:sp`:
[image]

When I try `:vsp` the reuslt here:
[image]

I really like to tweak horizontal with `fillchars` but vim seems don't allow users to do it. How can I disable completely that annoying bar?

Comment: so what exactly would you like to change. the vertical bar or the horizontal bar?

Comment: The horizontal bar please, if we can change horizontal bar like vertical bar in fillchars like `fillchars=horizontal:\-` would be great.

Comment: Yes, possible, but I'd like to keep this open.

Answer (score 4):

Just set the highlight of both the foreground and the background of the status line(s) to be the same colour as the background of the rest of the window:

```
:highlight StatusLine ctermfg=bg ctermbg=bg guibg=bg guifg=bg   
:highlight StatusLineNC ctermfg=bg ctermbg=bg guibg=bg guifg=bg
```

Comment: Well, at least this can be considered as a workaround solution. I tweaked mine like [this](https://imgur.com/a/1vNPs). But kind of, with many years and vim's philosophy we can't save some spaces for a decade. :)

Comment: Along with this answer to make a statusline look like an editable line -- I am thinking if it'd be feasible to do an `autocmd CursorMoved` along the lines of `:exe "setl stl=".fnameescape(getbufline(bufnr('%'),line("w$")+1)[0])` so we could get 1 more line shown... Seems a lot of tweaks are needed but theoretically we could've written a plugin for that :P

Comment: @SunnyPun That's a ridiculous idea. I love it!

Comment: @SunnyPun: How to make it work? I'm kind of noob here.

Comment: Sorry for being late! Have a look here: https://github.com/sunnypp/vim-horizon/ and please kindly tell me how many edge cases I have missed :P

Answer (score 3):

### OP's Question

(See if I got it correctly)

OP wanna have a `fillchars` for horizontal split line, just like the `|` for a vertical split.  `Fillchars` line up as a line to split the windows.

I am not sure how OP made the vertical `|` disappear -- did OP use `:set fillchars=\␣` (I mean the space) instead?

### My Attempt to Answer

From `:h fillchars`, we know that `:set fillchars=stl:-` would fill the empty space after the statusline with `-`.

And then, to get rid of the file name from the statusline, from `:h statusline` we know that the default is empty.  (That's why OP's attempt to do `:set statusline=` didn't remove the statusline)

-- so we have to set it to a single `-` by `:set statusline=-`.

Then the whole statusline (for an active Window) is now `----...` and what's left is to also do `:set fillchars+=stlnc:-`, so non-active Window also has a nice horizontal line for splits.

### Tl;dl;

```
:se stl=- fcs=stl:-,stlnc:-,vert:\|
```

Or a nicely documented one (for putting into a publicly shared `.vimrc`, maybe:

```
:set statusline=-        " hide file name in statusline
:set fillchars=stl:-     " fill active window's statusline with -
:set fillchars+=stlnc:-  " also fill inactive windows
:set fillchars+=vert:\|  " add a bar for vertical splits
```

For whatever reasons, we can also hide the most bottom statusline:

```
:set laststatus=0
```

Tested on my own Vim version 7.4.8056 on macOS with `vim -u /dev/null`.

Comment: More article [here](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/4744/hide-statusline-when-more-than-two-windows-open-without-suffering-the-extra-hidd). Basically we can't disable statusline yet. Even neovim has same issue. I'm surprised that people don't consider this as serious issue. Maybe use only `:vsp` or buffertab instead.

Comment: Just read the links, for my ViM by `:se ls=0` I don't have the bottom most statusline, and other "splitting lines" can be "emptied" using `:se stl=\␣  fcs=stl:\ ,stlnc:\ ,vert:\ `...  Is there any issues setting all of them to spaces?  Or you wanna even auto-hide the command line?

Comment: Yes, we can hide statusline at bottom but if you split it use `:sp`, top window will preserve a statusline and we can't hide/disable it.

Comment: Seems that the empty line isn't what you want.  Do you want an empty line that is same as the background color? (@Rich's answer) Or you want a very thin line to split the 2 documents... Or really _nothing_ between the 2 splits?

Comment: I would like `nothing` or at least `very thin` line.

Comment: it is not possible to hide the line completly, otherwise one couldn't see where one window ends and the other starts.

Comment: To see when one window ends, the user might look at the line number jump or the extended statusline just doesn't have a line number. I am thinking about a plugin to show an non-editable line -- just to give 1-line extended view.